# Accessing a static variable and setting it outside the class

Tags: ios, swift, static-variables

Here is a SubtitleCustomField class.

```
Class SubtitleCustomField: CustomCellField {
static var CellIdentifier: String!

  override init(frame: CGRect) {
  super.init(frame: frame)
  if CellIdentifier == "A" {
   //DO SOMETHINIG
  } else if CellIdentifier == "B" {
  //DO SOMETHING
  }

  }
}
```

Outside SubtitleCustomField class, I basically need to access static variable CellIdentifier, set value like "A", and trigger if statement to run.

In another class, Custom class, I've confirmed that I can access the static variable, CellIdentifier, in a following way:

```
Class Custom: CustomViewController {
     SubtitleCustomField.CellIdentifier = "part1_subtitle"
}
```

I face a problem at this point. In SubtitleCustomField class, I get an error on `if CellIdentifier == "A"` saying

> Static member 'CellIdentifier' cannot be used on instance of type
>   'SubtitleCustomField'

What would be the best approach I can use to achieve what I want? In summary, I want to set CellIdentifier variable outside SubtitleCustomField and trigger if statement with the value I set in SubtitleCustomField class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is trying to tell you that you are referring to a type property (static property) as if it was an instance property. You need to preface "CellIdentifier" with "SubtitleCustomField" in your SubtitleCustomField initializer just like you do when referring to it elsewhere.

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    if SubtitleCustomField.CellIdentifier == "A" {
        //DO SOMETHINIG
    } else if SubtitleCustomField.CellIdentifier == "B" {
        //DO SOMETHING
    }
}
```

You should always refer to type properties using the type name followed by "." followed by the property name.

Comment: I have further questions. (1) I need to do that way since it is a static variable right? (2) I've read some info on static variables and kinda confused. In documentation it says static variables are lazily instantiated and set the value once which can be used all over the instances of the class. If I'm kept changing value of CellIdentifier depends on my situations, would it cause any problems??

Comment: (1) Yes. The idea is that a static variable is a property of a type, so you access it using dot notation as if it were a property of the type itself rather than of the instance. (2) No. The initialization is only performed the first time you try to get the variable's value. After that you can set it to whatever you want. If you set the variable before getting it, then the lazy initialization is not performed.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you so much Marc!